# Program keeps printing a zero byte?

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I am trying to create a program that removes the vowels from a sentence. However, my program keeps failing because it keeps printing zero byte in the string. Would anyone be able to show me where I am going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int remove_all_vowels(int character);

int main(void) {

int character = getchar();
while (character != EOF && character != '\0') {

int new_character = remove_all_vowels(character);
putchar(new_character);

character = getchar();
}


return 0;

}

int remove_all_vowels(int character) {
if (character == 'a' || character == 'e' || character == 'i' || character 
== 'o' || character == 'u') {
return 0;
} else {
return character;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue (outputting null characters) comes from the fact that you unconditionally putchar(3) the result of `remove_all_vowels`, which returns 0 (null character) when given character is a vowel.

*To replace vowels with spaces:*

You can simply change `return 0;` in remove_all_vowels to `return ' ';`

*To completely remove vowels:*

I would suggest having a function just to help you check against vowels rather than having it act like a transformation over a char, which is really pythonest.

Example of code:

```
int is_vowel(int character) {
    return (
           character == 'a' || character == 'e' || character == 'i'
        || character == 'o' || character == 'u'
    );
}

// Then, in your main...
...
if (!is_vowel(character))
    putchar(character);
```

Answer (score -1):

your program works fine here 
`https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler`

Can give a screenshot whats the problem of your compiler?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_vowel(char);

int main()
{
  char s[100], t[100];
  int c, d = 0;

  printf("Enter a string to delete vowels\n");
  gets(s);

  for(c = 0; s[c] != '\0'; c++) {
    if(check_vowel(s[c]) == 0) {       // If not a vowel
      t[d] = s[c];
      d++;
    }
  }

  t[d] = '\0';

  strcpy(s, t);  // We are changing initial string. This is optional.

  printf("String after deleting vowels: %s\n", s);

  return 0;
}

int check_vowel(char ch)
{
    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'I' || ch =='o' || ch=='O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: While it is able to run, the problem with my program is that it prints zero bytes or null terminators. Do you know how I could prevent zero bytes from being printed?